# Why I cant use FrontSize in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Tetris.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="570" Width="525">

<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="127">
        <Label Content="Label" Height="56" Name="Scores" FrontSize="28" FrontWeight ="Bolt" />
        <Label Content="Label" Height="56" Name="Lines" FrontSize="28" FrontWeight="Bolt"/>
    </StackPanel>

</DockPanel>
```

So, I try to use FrontSize and FrontWeight in my Label but it didnt work - Whats my mistake? By the way, my last FrontWeight actually works.

Comment: no it does not work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "Font", not "Front", and "Bold", not "Bolt" (ironically, given my name):

```
        <Label Content="Label" Height="56" Name="Scores" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Label Content="Label" Height="56" Name="Lines" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

Comment: omg--- yes of course...  im from germany so spelling mistakes like this happens all the time... Thank u "BoltClock" ;-) haha!

Comment: That's OK, it takes a bit more rep to be able to upvote. You can mark it accepted in a few minutes by clicking the tick mark just under the vote arrows. Glad I helped!

Comment: @user3013837, how are you typing in your XAML? Both Visual Studio and Blend have intellisense that allow selecting the correct attributes. They both also show tooltips if your attributes are unrecognized.